# deleted path variable in windows 10 and when I recreate it and come back after is not there

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

**Hi**
**first of all I'm very sorry for posting question that has been asked a lot before 
but none of those couldn't solve my problem**
I had problems with creating JAVA_HOME variable and at the meanwhile I accidentally deleted path variable in user section
I'll be grateful if you can help me restore it or do something about it

Answer (score 0):

Restore from your last disk image or use Windows Restore.

Few PATH variables are actually needed in Windows 10, anyway, and for programs that need them and stop working, just reinstall that application.

For what it's worth, here are mine:

[image: PATH]